# Correct form of derivative

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics

In the equations

$$\mathbf{F} = \mathbf{-\mathit{e}(E + v \times B)} = m\frac{d\mathbf{v}}{dt}$$  $$\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}= -\frac{e}{m}\left(E_x + B_z\frac{dy}{dt}- B_y \frac{dz}{dt}\right)$$ $$\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}=-\frac{e}{m}\left(E_y+B_x\frac{dz}{dt}-B_z\frac{dx}{dt}\right)$$
$$\frac{d^2z}{dt^2}=-\frac{e}{m}\left(E_z+B_y\frac{dx}{dt}-B_x\frac{dy}{dt}\right)$$

Is it correct to use $d$ or should I use $\partial$?

([Reference for equations](https://ecedmans.files.wordpress.com/2014/10/microwave-devices-and-circuits-samuel-liao.pdf): Liao, Samuel Y. Microwave Devices and Circuits. Englewood Cliffs, NJ: Prentice-Hall, 1980. Print. Page 12.)

Comment: It appears $x,y,z$ are functions of the independent variable $t$ only. In this case $\dfrac{d}{dt}, \dfrac{\partial}{\partial t}$ operate the same. I would say the first is best, since the partial derivative may cause confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here $x$, $y$ and $z$ appear to be functions of only the one variable $t$ (representing, I suppose, the coordinates of a particle at time $t$).  There is no other variable in sight, and you're certainly not taking derivatives with respect to any other variable.  So $d$ is correct.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I thought, but I wanted to make sure.